# How do I use MPI_Allgather

Tags: mpi

I'm testing out MPI_Allgather, and I'm getting strange results...
The following code gives me an output of: "P0 received: 0,42,-1780253336,42,".
The only correct result there is the 1st one, as they're all sending their ranks. The output should be: "0, 1, 2, 3,". I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working as expected.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rank = 0;
    int size = 0;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int* arr = new int[4];

    MPI_Allgather(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, arr, 4, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank == 0)
    {
    printf("P0 received: ");
    for(int i=0; i< 4; i++)
        printf("%i,", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    }
    delete arr;
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: The receive count argument in `MPI_Allgather` is per _process_, not total.  You want to be receiving 1 int per process, not 4.  So you want `MPI_Allgather(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, arr, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. If you want, you can answer the question and I'll mark it as answered, that way it'll show up in searches as 'answered', and you get the reputation.